# Data Item Explorer

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am totally lost. I got a "Data Item Explorer" and no idea really how to scrape the data from here:

http://marketinformation.natgrid.co.uk/gas/frmDataItemExplorer.aspx

Following selection should apply:

-> Linepack -> Closing Linepack -> Predicted Closing Linepack (PCLP1)
and
-> Opening Linepack -> Opening linepack (interim)

and under criteria it should be
Applicable for "Gas day" (today's day is set by default)

When making above selection, click in lower left corner on "View Data on Data items" I receive the desire output that I am trying to scrape.

Can anyone kindly provide some direction?

Thanks in advance.
P.

Comment: Nothing that much, not really worth posting: opening the URL, and get the frontpage code with beautifulsoup. I am struggling with the interaction in the form.

Comment: I created a follow up here with code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350797/controlnotfounderror-asp-mechanize-javascript-python

Comment: A suggestion for the future. Next time edit and update the same question instead of opening a new one..

Answer (score 1):

Since your target, an asp.net web form, uses ViewState to pass parameters(user input) to server side, you better

1. Open browser developer tools according to your browser. Go to network panel.
2. Manually click out a result page following your mentioned steps.
3. Read over the post data sent to frmDataItemExplorer.aspx especially of __VIEWSTATE.
4. Send those data yourself.

The reason why your steps didn't work is because asp.net web form will not just read the input data, but also need to trigger some javascript events and put those user input into VIEWSTATE, which is the true source of parameters.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. I am on Firefox and not quite sure what you mean with step 2, 3 and 4. What do you mean with "click out a result page"? Also, how can I send that data to myself? Thanks!

Comment: I mean you do all the selection and submit the form. Then under network panel you should see a list of http request/response. Find the item named frmDataItemExplorer.aspx and copy all the request data to your code(or simply copy as curl).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you kindly provide some sample code?