# ControlNotFoundError (ASP, Mechanize, Javascript, Python)

Tags: python, mechanize

I am receiving following response from the server

```
ctrlDateTime%24txtSpecifyFromDate=05%2F02%2F2015&
ctrlDateTime%24rgApplicable=rdoApplicableFor&
ctrlDateTime%24txtSpecifyToDate=05%2F02%2F2015&
```

I am trying with

```
br["ctrlDateTime%24txtSpecifyFromDate"]="05%2F02%2F2015";
br["ctrlDateTime%24rgApplicable"]="rdoApplicableFor";
br["ctrlDateTime%24txtSpecifyToDate"]="05%2F02%2F2015";
```

How can I fix ControlnotfoundError? Here is my code:

Any idea how to solve it?

```
import mechanize
import re

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0')]
response = br.open("http://marketinformation.natgrid.co.uk    /gas/frmDataItemExplorer.aspx")


br.select_form(nr=0)

br.set_all_readonly(False)
mnext = re.search("""<a id="lnkNext" href="javascript:__doPostBack('(.*?)','(.*?)')">XML""", html)

br["tvDataItem_ExpandState"]="cccccccceennncennccccccccc";
br["tvDataItem_SelectedNode"]="";
br["__EVENTTARGET"]="lbtnCSVDaily";
br["__EVENTARGUMENT"]="";
br["tvDataItem_PopulateLog"]="";
br["__VIEWSTATE"]="%2FwEP.....SNIP....%2F90SB9E%3D";
br["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]="B2D04314";
br["__EVENTVALIDATION"]="%2FwEW...SNIP...uPceSw%3D%3D";
br["txtSearch"]="";
br["tvDataItemn11CheckBox"]="on";
br["tvDataItemn15CheckBox"]="on";
br["ctrlDateTime%24txtSpecifyFromDate"]="05%2F02%2F2015";
br["ctrlDateTime%24rgApplicable"]="rdoApplicableFor";
br["ctrlDateTime%24txtSpecifyToDate"]="05%2F02%2F2015";
br["btnViewData"]="View+Data+for+Data+Items";
br["hdnIsAddToList"]="";

response = br.submit()

print(response.read());
```

Thanks in advance.
P.

Comment: This is solved in two steps: 1) I replaced %24 with '$'; 2) some of the parameters required a true parameter to be passed on and some to be passed on as ['<string>',]

Answer (score 0):

This is solved in two steps: 1) I replaced %24 with '$'; 2) some of the parameters required a true parameter to be passed on and some to be passed on as ['',]